# What's the difference between EIP and public IP in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, eip

Anything different between EIP and Public IP in AWS?

If launch an instance in EC2-Classic, EIP = Public IP?
If launch an instance in EC2-VPC, the public IP of an instance can be the NAT address?

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between EIP and a public IP is the lifetime. If you have an EIP, it can remain with you even if there is no instance with which it is associated. However, the Public IPs are returned to the pool (and you may not get them back) as soon as you stop/terminate a VM.

You get a public Ip when you create a VM. But EIP is optional. If you associate an EIP with an instance, the same IP will continue to be available as the public IP of the VM no matter how many times you stop and start it. However, if there is no EIP associated with a VM, every time you stop and start the same VM instance, it is extremely likely that it gets associated with a different public IP.